TypeScript tsconfig Error: 'compilerOptions/lib/2' Must Be Equal to One of the Allowed Values
I'm working on a React Native project and encountering a strange error related to the lib setting in my tsconfig.json. Here is the content of my tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM"],
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["react", "react-native", "jest"]
  }
}

I keep getting this error:
'compilerOptions/lib/2' must be equal to one of the allowed values 'ES5, ES6, ES2015, ES2015.Collection, ... Value found 'es2020.date' Or 'compilerOptions/lib/2' must match pattern ...

The error seems to indicate that I chose es2020.date, but I didn't – I selected "ES2020". I've tried different values like "ES6", but the compiler always thinks I chose es2020.date.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I fix this?
Additional Info:

React Native version: 0.75.1
React version: 18.3.1
TypeScript version: 5.0.4
@react-native/typescript-config: 0.75.1
Node version: >=18
Package manager: Yarn 3.6.4
VS Code version: 1.79.2
Operating System: Windows 11
I've tried clearing cache, re-installing dependencies, and making various changes to tsconfig.json.

Thanks in advance!

"compilerOptions/lib/2" means the item at index 2 of the lib array (i.e. the third item) but you only have two items so the error is coming from somewhere else. And I strongly suspect the root cause is using such an old version of Typescript – presumably some library isn't compatible with it.

@GuyIncognito you're right. There are only 2 items, but the compiler is pointing to a 3rd non-existent item. Thanks to your comment, I took a look at the extension file ("extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json") and realized that the 3rd item was actually in this external file all along.
